# Android: Threat implicit intent in a class that is not an Activity or BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to start an app with an implicit intent, but before that app starts, I need to process the intent and start a state machine that will then load an `Activity`.

I can do this either using a broadcast receiver or an activity

```
<receiver android:name="com.13.MyBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.13.StartStateMachine" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But then I have no control if other app will respond to this same intent.

or

```
<activity android:name="com.13.MyReceiverActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.13.StartStateMachine" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity >
```

But this would not be clean, I can do some processing `onCreate()` and then `finish()`.

Any idea if I can have a combination of these methods?
I mean use an implicit (or explicit) intent to load a class (that is not a `BroadcastReceiver` or `Activity`) from another app?

Comment: "I want to start an app with an implicit intent" -- some other app is starting your app. Why would that app use an implicit `Intent` to start your app? Who will be writing this other app? "But then I have no control if other app will respond to this same intent" -- you lack that control over implicit `Intents` in general. You have no control over whether some other app has an activity that responds to your implicit `Intent`. "I mean use an implicit (or explicit) intent to load a class (that is not a BroadcastReceiver or Activity) from another app? " -- nothing that will address your concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have the code for both apps.

Comment: Then why are you using an implicit `Intent`? If you control both apps, and you want App A to start App B, then use an explicit `Intent`. Or, start with an implicit `Intent`, use `PackageManager` to determine what component from App B supports that `Intent`, and use that information to make the `Intent` explicit.

Comment: I do not want necessary to use an implicit intent but considered it at a better solution that an explicit one. Also, I use Package Manger to check it, as you suggested.

This works now with an implicit intent + an activity just to process my intent and start the state machine, but I think this approach is kind of dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both apps are yours, you are welcome to use whatever IPC mechanism that you want.

The advantage of using an `Activity` is that you have the option of saying everything is in the same task. So, when App A starts an activity of App B, that can all be one task. Any other IPC mechanism will force you to start a new task.

So, as I suggested in a comment, use `PackageManager` to convert your implicit `Intent` into an explicit one. Then, use whatever IPC that you want. If you want to use a "broadcast" (where the explicit `Intent` really makes it more of a "narrowcast"), you are welcome to do so.

IMHO, saying that an activity transfers control to another activity, perhaps using `finish()`, is not really "dirty". After all, many of the splash screens that apps use wind up doing just that. IMHO, using any other IPC mechanism to start an activity, when `startActivity()` would work just fine, is "dirty".

Comment: Thanks, I do not like using an activity in this way but it seems I have no choice.